# Volume of Laptop speaker very low

Tags: 14.04, sound

I am using HP-Pavilion-TS-Sleekbook. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The volume of the laptop speaker is very low even if it's in full high. I have used the same laptop with Windows 8 and the volume was working fine.

I have tried with existing posts in this forum but the issue is still persisting. Please provide me a solution by which I can fix the low volume issue in my laptop.

Thanks,
-Atish

Comment: did you try raising the PCM? alsamixer -Dhw

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Gain control to ALSA

```
sudo nano /etc/asound.conf
```

and Add this to the file

```
    pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm “softvol”
}
pcm.softvol {
        type softvol
        slave {
                pcm “dmix”
        }
        control {
                name “Pre-Amp”
                card 0
        }
        min_dB -5.0
        max_dB 20.0
        resolution 6
}
```

Source:  http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/adding-an-alsa-software-pre-amp-to-fix-low-sound-levels/

Comment: I tried as per your direction but it didn't work for me. I tried changing "plug" with "hw" also but still no luck.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes. I rebooted and check.  I tried certain other tricks also. But still no luck. The Volume is very low.